# Vscode will not autofocus on integrated terminal while running code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run without debugging in python on vscode it no longer autofocuses on the terminal forcing me to click into the terminal everytime to input data. Is there any solution to cause vscode to autofocus when code is running?

Comment: The mouse will stay in the position you left before running. You can click the terminal and then run the file, so that it always focuses on the terminal. If this doesn't solve the problem, I'll submit it to GIT.

Comment: I am trying to improve economy of clicks, I want my mouse to automatically move to the terminal when I hit run. I seem to remember this as a feature but I must have been mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/17884) has been tested on **Visual Studio Code** 1.74.3.

1. Install the [Python](https://vscode:extension/ms-python.python) extension for Visual Studio Code.
2. Go to `File` >> `Preferences` >> `Settings`.
3. In the `Search settings` field enter, "Python › Terminal: Focus After Launch"
4. Click on, `When launching a python terminal, whether to focus the cursor on the terminal.`
5. A check mark should appear in the tick box.

Done! Now every time you `Run Python File` the terminal will be focused.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no relevant implementation method for code runner at present. You could use shortcut `"Ctrl+~"` to foucus on the terminal, and I will submit the function to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Two Fixes/Workarounds I utilized.

Autohotkey Script:

```
F9::
Send {F5}
Sleep 200
SendInput ^{~}
```

Or Rebind:

View: Toggle Terminal Originally  (Ctrl + ~)  to F5 so jumps to the terminal everytime you run